# Saving open file list and buffer command history in between sessions

Tags: buffers, files, eval-expression, savehist-mode

I've discovered `desktop-save-mode` which allows Emacs to be closed and when it reopens, it appears with the same files that were open before.

I want to take this a bit further and I was wondering if I could also:

1. Save the history of files I've open with `C-x C-f`. I often end up opening the same files, so it'd be great to easily find those. If not possible to save this, maybe some bookmarks would help?
2. Save the history of buffer commands executed via `M-x` or `M-:`, is this possible? If not possible, maybe I could keep some snippets around to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `savehist` library is the general option for persisting variable values across sessions.

Simply enabling `savehist-mode` ensures that most minibuffer histories will persist, but you can also tell it to do likewise for any other variable, by adding it to `savehist-additional-variables`:

```el
(eval-after-load "savehist"
 '(add-to-list 'savehist-additional-variables 'foo))

(savehist-mode 1)
```

See also: <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-group` <kbd>RET</kbd> `savehist` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

For file history, if you enable `ido-mode` and customize `ido-use-virtual-buffers` to t, even closed buffers remain in the ido history.  This persists across `desktop.el` sessions.

`C-k` during an `ido-switch-buffer` removes the selected buffer from the history, if you need to get it out of your way.

Comment: Is something like this available for helm?

Comment: @vfclists yeah, there's a builtin "*Helm Source*" for `ido` virtual buffers and another for `recentf` files. (1) use `M-x helm-mini` instead of `M-x helm-buffer` , which merges that *Helm Source* with the source for open buffers and with a "dummy source". (2) iirc, enable the option which says to "use recentf buffers instead of ido virtual buffers".

Comment: (tldr `M-x helm-mini`)

Comment: e.g. `(defcustom helm-mini-default-sources '(helm-source-buffers-list helm-source-recentf helm-source-buffer-not-found))` source https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/blob/v3.2/helm-buffers.el#L92

Comment: And for ivy, there's `(setq ivy-use-virtual-buffers t)`